# Same word giving true and false for same query in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgres-10

I'm having a same data in 2 different table columns. When I comparing it returns `False`.

```
select (case when 'Gurgaon / Delhi – NCR' = 'Gurgaon / Delhi - NCR' then true else false end)
```

But when copy and compare the same column text it returns `True`

```
select (case when 'Gurgaon / Delhi – NCR' = 'Gurgaon / Delhi – NCR' then true else false end)
```

How those word differs and how can I find and resolve this?

**UPDATE**
In table one column stored as `\96` and I changed to **`-`**. Is that causing the problem?

Comment: yes, - – are two different characters

Comment: How can I input the second one?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need a  CASE expression for that. You can simplify it to `'Gurgaon / Delhi – NCR' = 'Gurgaon / Delhi – NCR'` that already returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to replace a character by another in a string, you can use the `REPLACE()` function.

This function is described in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

For example: `SELECT REPLACE('Gurgaon / Delhi – NCR', '–', '-')`

After that you could have a match between your two strings if it is that you still want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Thanks for the edit. I forgot to put the code in good form.